# How to create a Grafana folder through Pulumi

Tags: typescript, grafana, pulumi

I am able to install and import Grafana dashboards in an Azure Kubernetes Service using Pulumi through a HelmRelease Custom Resource Definition of the `kube-prometheus-stack`.

I was able to do some `ConfigMaps` to import dashboards that I previously stored as JSON files.

What I am now trying to do is to put those imported dashboards inside custom folders in Grafana.

How can I create such folders (first problem) and how do I state the folder for each dashboard I am importing?

Example of the way I import a dashboard (actually landing in the root folder in Grafana):

```
const myDashboard = fs.readFileSync(
  'dashboards/myDashboard.json',
  'utf-8'
);

new k8s.core.v1.ConfigMap(
  'my-dashboard-cm',
  {
    metadata: {
      name: 'my-dashboard',
      namespace: args.namespace,
      labels: { grafana_dashboard: '1' },
    },
    data: { 'my-dashboard.json': JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(myDashboard)) },
  },
  { parent: this }
);
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the directory of your dashboard by setting the folder annotation called `k8s-sidecar-target-directory`.

It should look like below on a Pulumi object.

```
new k8s.core.v1.ConfigMap(
  'my-dashboard-cm',
  {
    metadata: {
      name: 'my-dashboard',
      namespace: args.namespace,
      labels: { grafana_dashboard: '1' },
      annotations : { "k8s-sidecar-target-directory" : "/tmp/dashboards/yourfolder"                                     }
    },
    data: { 'my-dashboard.json': JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(myDashboard)) },
  },
  { parent: this }
);
```

You might want to set `sidecar.dashboards.provider.foldersFromFilesStructure:true` on your main chart values so you'd have the same folder name in Grafana menu.